# Longest Name in the list and Average birth date of all

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, split

My aim is to calculate the birth date of each person in the list we input as shown below and also output the longest name between them.

Desired output:

```
sauli,1948
tarja,1943
martti,1936
mauno,1923
urho,1900

Longest name: martti
Average of the birth years: 1930.0
```

My Code is working but it doesn't output the longest name and correct average.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PersonalDetails {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int sum = 0, count = 0;
        double avg = 0;
        String name;
        String[] pcs;
        String txt;
        
        while(true){
            txt = in.nextLine();
            pcs = txt.split(",");
            
            if(txt.equals("")){
                break;
            }
            
            sum += Integer.valueOf(pcs[1]);
            count++;
        }
        
        String lng = "";
        int low = pcs[0].length();
        for(int i=0; i<txt.length(); i++){
            if(low < pcs[i].length()){
                lng = pcs[i];
            }
        }
        
        if(count>0){
            avg = (double) sum/count;
        }
        
        System.out.println("Longest Name: " + lng);
        System.out.println("Average of the birth years: " + avg);
    }
}
`
```

Comment: When you use a debugger, what is the *first* line that doesn't do what you expected?

Comment: @ScottHunter it doesn't check at all. It just print "String lng = "";" this as the longest.

Comment: Please explain `i<txt.length()`.

Comment: If your code doesn't produce the longest name and doesn't calculate the average then it is not working. Consider solving this in parts - write separate methods to collect the record data, find the longest name, and find the average birth year.  You do not gain appreciable performance by trying to do everything at once.

Answer (score 1):

/* Because you don't save your names to an array and try to get the last input from the scanner which is only empty! to make your program work, you need to initialize an array and save your names to it, after that try to find which name is the longest */

```
name = names.get(0);
      for(int i=1; i<names.size(); i++){
       if ( name.length()< names.get(i).length()) {
    name = names.get(i);
     }
            
     }
```

/* Another way to resolve your issue is by comparing each input directly and saving it to a variable. */

```
 while(true){
 txt = in.nextLine();
 pcs = txt.split(",");
    if(name.length()< pcs[0].length()) {
 name=pcs[0];
}
 if(txt.equals("")){
 break;
}
 sum += Integer.valueOf(pcs[1]);
count++;
 }
```